# Centos: How to revert to a revert back to an earlier version of a package?

Tags: centos, installation, remove

I have installed version 6.4 of filebeat and then I decided to revert back to 1.3. So I used the command 'yum remove filebeat-6.4.0-x86_64.rpm', to remove it, when I try to install filebeat 1.3 I get the error:

```
package filebeat-6.4.0-1.x86_64 (which is newer than filebeat-1.3.1-1.x86_64) is already installed
file /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml from install of filebeat-1.3.1-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package filebeat-6.4.0-1.x86_64
file /etc/init.d/filebeat from install of filebeat-1.3.1-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package filebeat-6.4.0-1.x86_64
file /usr/bin/filebeat from install of filebeat-1.3.1-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package filebeat-6.4.0-1.x86_64
file /lib/systemd/system/filebeat.service from install of filebeat-1.3.1-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package filebeat-6.4.0-1.x86_64
```

It looks like, the config files are not removed, so I tried to remove the path in the error message to avoid the conflicts, but I still get the same error message. I found that the right command to remove a package is to use '--remove-leaves', so I tried to reinstall version 6.4, so I can remove everything afterwards, when I try to install it, it says 'nothing to do' as it detects version 6.4 is already installed, now when I do `'yum remove *filebeat* --remove-leaves'`, `'No Match for argument: filebeat-6.4.0-x86_64.rpm'`, and so it does not do anything. How can I cleanly remove the remaining files?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following sequence and it worked:

```
yum reinstall filebeat-6.4.0-x86_64.rpm
yum remove filebeat --remove-leaves
yum install filebeat-1.3.1-x86_64.rpm
```